# Did the Cybermen ever have a civil war?

Tags: doctor-who, cybermen

It is well established that during the Dalek history, that they have had various civil wars. I don't think this has ever been explored in the TV series, but is anyone aware of sources involving different factions of the Cybermen engaging in a civil war?

Comment: Would that mean there's *two* things they're better than Daleks at?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

I've read through the entirety of https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Cyberman#History, and at no point in any officially-licensed media have two factions of Cybermen fought against each other.

Whenever two separate groups meet, it seems they always willingly join together.

Comment: what stories did two factions meet?

Comment: @jim the book _Killing Ground_ apparently. It's also implied in the TV series that the Cybus Cybermen merged with the "regular" Cybermen.